# Grant alter on only one column in table

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, sql-grant

I want to grant a user only to edit one column in my table. What command do I use here? I use the oracle 11g database. I alrdy know how I can grant only read or delete on the whole table but how do I do it for only one column or more? pls give an example.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

For example, you want to grant update privilege on ename column only, then give the following statement (where xyz is the username)

```
grant update (ename) on emp to xyz;
```

Syntax:

```
grant update(column-name) on table-name to user-name
```

**EDIT:** (for granting select privilege)

To grant select statement on emp table to XYZ and to make XYZ be able to further pass on this privilege you have to give WITH GRANT OPTION clause in GRANT statement like this.

```
grant select on emp to xyz with grant option;
```

Also,
For example you want to grant update privilege on ename column only and insert privilege on empno and ename columns only, you can do this:

```
grant update (ename),insert (empno, ename)  on emp to xyz;
```

Comment: thx that worked perfect but i just red that it is not working with select statements. I made as an alternative a view. is this correct

Comment: u mean..one cannot grant select privilege? well i think we can grant select privilege too, check edit

Comment: Note: You must grant the SELECT privilege on the table along with the UPDATE privilege.

Answer (score 6):

Based on [this source](http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/column_privileges.htm):

Only `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `REFERENCES` privileges can be granted at the column level. When granting `INSERT` at the column level, you must include all the not null columns in the row.

Here is an example:

```
GRANT update (column_name) ON table_name TO user_name;
```